# Python: Fit geometric forms into a board matrix?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

In the past few days i was thinking of a solution for an AI problem. The problem sounds like this:

I want to determine an arrangement for a few given geometric forms(that do not exceed the given board size) on a square board of given size, in such a way that the board will be uniform covered and the forms will
not overlap.

I want to apply Depth first search / Greedy best first search, but it feels difficult to find a proper representation of the forms and the actual board in order to traverse it. I'm new to python so that makes it a bit more difficult. Any suggestions?

Visual example:

[image: Forms]

[image: Board]

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @RosaGronchi You could imagine something like a tetris game. You would have a few forms exactly like those in tetris, which you could use one after another to add them up, one on top of the other. You can also rotate the forms...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation ?

Comment: Well, I'm just not sure how to represent the forms...and how would I traverse the matrix using DFS/GBFS. Tessellation..feels like it gets too complicated. I'm just referring to completing a simple matrix's squares with the forms. But in order to do that i need to search using DFS/GBFS where would i best start completing the matrix so that the existing forms in the matrix do not overlap.

Comment: @RosaGronchi added two images representing the forms and the board

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a variation on rectangle/square fitting. Versions of the problem exist where unused cells have to be minimised for an optimal placement of the figures, whereas other versions, like the one you are describing, require for the whole board to be covered uniformly. These are called 'perfect square/rectangle placement' problems.

Typical ways to solve these problems involve the usage of finite integer domains representing the variables of the rectangles and a set of constraints making sure the geometrical placements are valid ones (i.e. don't cross the board borders, don't overlap with each other mutually, ..).

Comment: Lets say the filled squares on the board have value 1 and empty ones have value 0.
I was thinking of having the initial board as a matrix and construct for each  other form a matrix so that when i add the form to the board I wouldn't get values > 1 (which represent overlapping).

But its still not clear of how i would traverse the matrix using DFS/GBFS.

Comment: Added images so it is easier to understand.

Comment: That is indeed a good way to model this problem, as every cell 'knows' how many figures can overlap with it, uniformly covering every cell becomes easy. Have a look at [this](http://4c.ucc.ie/~hsimonis/shikaku.pdf) paper using ECLiPSe as programming language, it might be of good use/inspiration to you. As for the search you have the choice between partial search (as explained in the paper: compute all placements on beforehand to reduce final search space) or search while simultaneously placing the figures. Of course, both have their advantages and disadvantages.